# Delphi HMRC test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk/hello/world

Tags: json, rest, http, delphi

I'm trying the HMRC Developers HUB tutorials from:

https://developer.service.hmrc.gov.uk/api-documentation/docs/tutorials

I have tried two ways of the "Hello World", but keep getting:

```
{"code":"ACCEPT_HEADER_INVALID","message":"The accept header is missing or invalid"}
```

Example 1 REST Client:

```
procedure TForm1.btnTest_REST_ClientClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  jValue: TJSONValue;
begin
  RESTClient1.BaseURL := cbHMRC_Test_URLs.Text;
  RESTRequest1.Execute;

  jValue := RESTResponse1.JSONValue;
  MemoContent.Text:= jValue.ToString;
end;
```

[image: With a RESTRequest header of:-]

Example 2 TdHTTP:

```
procedure TForm1.btnTest_HTTPClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  get_url: string;
  resp: TMemoryStream;
begin
  get_url := 'https://test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk/hello/world';
  resp := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    IdHttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Accept', 'application/vnd.hmrc.1.0+json');
    IdHTTP1.Get(get_url, resp);

    resp.Position := 0; // <-- add this!!
    MemoContent.Lines.LoadFromStream(resp);
  finally
    resp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Both make the connection, but fail on the Header.

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Please refer this page for asking good question which usually get upvoted,which helps in getting good answer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest going with the REST components.  I've used them significantly and they work quite well.

On the REST component side, your just missing the Request Accept value:

```
RESTRequest1.Accept := 'application/vnd.hmrc.1.0+json';
```

I tested your example to their hello world resource and received:

```
{"message":"Hello World"}
```

Looks like it's working.

Comment: Thanks Randy.That now works. I can move on and try the other HMRC test examples.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you struggling like me with how to implement the initial HMRC tutorials in Delphi, try the following.

Create a new application.  I chose a Multi-Device / Blank Application option.

On the main form, add the following components:-

TRESTClient
TRESTRequest
TRESTResponse
TMemo
TButton

Add the System.JSON unit to the uses clause.

Set the Button1Click procedure as follows:-

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  jValue: TJSONValue;


begin

  RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'https://test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk/hello/world';
  RESTRequest1.Accept := 'application/vnd.hmrc.1.0+json';
  RESTRequest1.Execute;

  jValue := RESTResponse1.JSONValue;
  Memo1.Text:= jValue.ToString;
end;
```

Run the program, click the button and voila!

I hope this helps someone